# Spring Batch onSkipInWrite to get Item object rather than entity object

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using spring batch for reading data from csv.

The Item Class is `EmployeeItem` where I set the values from CSV.

During persist when any exception is thrown for example DataIntegrity Violation, the process is skipped and the skipped data is written to the error file.

`onSkipInWrite` where I will get only the `Employee` entity.

```
public void onSkipInWrite(Employee item, Throwable t) {
   errorItemWriter.write(items);
}
```

If its a validation error during the process time

```
public void onSkipInProcess(EmployeeItem item, Throwable t) {
}
```

I will get an `EmployeeItem` object which I can directly write the skipped data to the error file, but in the case of `onSkipInWrite` I will get the `Employee` entity only.

I have to reset the values from `Employee` to `EmployeeItem`

Any possibility to get the `EmployeeItem` in `onSkipInWrite`?

Comment: Show your processor and writer configuration. Also,  how are you defining these methods - by annotation or by implementing `SkipListener`?

Comment: implements SkipListener

Comment: <batch:job id="batchProvision">
  <batch:step id="employeeStep">
   <batch:tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="${employee.batch.throttle.limit}">
    <batch:chunk reader="synchronizedEmployeeReader"
     processor="compositeEmployeeItemProcessor" writer="employeeWriter"
     commit-interval="${employee.batch.commit.interval}"
        skip-limit="${employee.batch.skip.limit}"
        retry-limit="${employee.batch.retry.limit}">